# Как вернуть не html данные из doGet(e)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Есть 2 скрипта на разных аккаунтах.

На первом(клиент) скрипт:

```
function sent() {
  url = /** * //адрес запроса */ ;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
  if (/*  */) {
    /*   */
  } else {
    response = "Выбирите правильный диапазон"
  }
  ui.alert(response)
}
```

Второй

```
function doGet(e) {
  try{
    if(e){
        var rez = "Порядок в "+ new Date();
      }else{
        var rez = "Ошибка в "+ new Date();
      }   
  } catch (c) {
    var rez = "произошла ошибка; "+c
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(rez);
}
```

в итоге алерт выдаёт такой ответ:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="chromevox" content-script="no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/macros/client/css/1161659322-mae_html_css_ltr.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/macros/client/js/4110720394-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js"></script>

</head>

<body role="main">
  <table id="warning-bar-table" class="full_size" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="warning" class="warning-bar"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 100%"><iframe id="sandboxFrame" allow="accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay *; camera *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture-in-picture *; speaker *; usb *; vibrate *; vr *" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation">
    </iframe>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      var el = document.getElementById('sandboxFrame');
      el.onload = function() {
        goog.script.init("\x7b\x22functionNames\x22:\x5b\x22onOpen\x22,\x22onInstall\x22,\x22AddGroup\x22,\x22test1\x22,\x22AddCont\x22,\x22doGet\x22,\x22updCont\x22,\x22addCont\x22,\x22showSidebar\x22,\x22FirstExampleFunc\x22\x5d,\x22sandboxMode\x22:\x22IFRAME_SANDBOX\x22,\x22libid\x22:\x22MElN2r1cq8wq5AsjRzfOOkBKSiheyHQNG\x22,\x22callbackTimeout\x22:390000,\x22eei\x22:\x22\x22,\x22sandboxHost\x22:\x22https:\/\/n-d3laszmtlpgq7xsnt6ua7gljuor6fxn3fxgqplq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com\x22,\x22clientSideProperties\x22:\x7b\x22google.script.sandbox.mode\x22:\x22IFRAME_SANDBOX\x22,\x22google.script.host.origin\x22:\x22https:\/\/docs.google.com\x22\x7d,\x22actionPrefix\x22:\x22\/macros\/s\/AKfycbyoX5A8Ab-5Q12kufXr7PWUI4Vd8htVWKdLI842l0-s1DT-DJo\x22,\x22userHtml\x22:\x22Порядок в Sat May 26 2018 16:50:02 GMT+0300 (EAT)\x22,\x22ncc\x22:\x22\x7b\\\x22awhs\\\x22:true\x7d\x22\x7d", "", undefined, true, false, false, "false", "https:\/\/n-d3laszmtlpgq7xsnt6ua7gljuor6fxn3fxgqplq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com");
      }
      el.src = 'https:\/\/n-d3laszmtlpgq7xsnt6ua7gljuor6fxn3fxgqplq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com\/userCodeAppPanel';
    }());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

В строке `goog.script.init(...` есть искомый мной параметр: `...userHtml\x22:\x22`**Порядок в Sat May 26 2018 16:50:02 GMT+0300 (EAT)**`\x22,...`

Мне нужен только этот ответ. Как его правильно передать или вытащить? А то у меня только одна идея – парсить ответ как текст и через substr() доставать его, но я понимаю, что это не тот метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно возвращать не только HTML

```
function doGet(e) {
  try {
    if (e) {
      var rez = "Порядок в " + new Date();
    } else {
      var rez = "Ошибка в " + new Date();
    }
  } catch (c) {
    var rez = "произошла ошибка; " + c
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(rez);
}
```

Подробнее 
[Content Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/)

Comment: Спасибо, всё сработала

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = {
    "id": 100
};
// Возвращаем ответ апи
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(result))
                    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```